# Installing my own XP VHD into Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine

I am following [these instructions](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2009/09/how-to-make-your-own-vhd-to-xp-mode-or-even-vista-mode-ready/) to install my own XP VHD into Windows 7 Virtual PC (XP Mode).

When I click on Install Integration Components on the Tools menu the setup does not start. I don't understand the message that comes up because I can't start the VM at this point at all. It says:

> If setup does not run automatically, open the CD-ROM drive inside the virtual machine and run setup.

What does it mean when I can't run the VM?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to sort the wrong problem. The Integration Components are not essential    and hence are not stopping the vm from running. You need to fix this problem first.

Comment: From the article I posted it says that a setting needs to changed to use your own VHD. This meant getting integration components enabled as far as I know. Why else wouldn't the VHD start??

Comment: That's not how I interpret the article. I think it is saying that if you have an existing VHD which works as a normal virtual machine, you can 'update' it to work in 'XP mode' (so that, for example, programs installed in the virtual machine appear in the programs menu of the real machine).

I have several VHD's which don't have the Integration Components installed. 

When you say the vm will not start, do you get any error messages?
Is the the vm that will not start, or the o/s inside the vm that won't start? (And if the latter, will it start in safe mode).

Also do you have any working Vm's ?

Comment: All i see is some text scroll up then black screen. I only have the default xp mode that works. How do find out why it won't boot?

Comment: Its the o/s inside that won't start.

Comment: It is actully hibernated it says.

Comment: Was the VHD originally hibernated? As I recall, migrating vhd's in this state is not supported and you may have to 'power off' the vm to force the operating to boot up normally.

Also, you can try booting into safe mode and uninstalling any existing guest additions.

Comment: you have to to to settings in the settings they have a dvd/cdrom icon that lets you MOUNT a ISO to install OR to use your ACTUAL cd rom drive you have connected to INSTALL windows.